# How do I keep these bullet points centered, but have the bullets aligned to the left together

Tags: html, github, markdown

```
<p align="center"><small>
- Total number of months included in the dataset <br>
- Net total amount of profit/losses over the entire period <br> 
- Average of the changes in profit/losses over the entire period <br> 
- Greatest increase in profits (date and amount) over the entire period <br> 
- Greatest decrease in losses (date and amount) over the entire period <br> 
</small></p>
```

I am trying to get these bullet points to stay in the center but I want them to be straight up and down with the bullet points if that makes sense. Can anyone help? This is for a README.md file on github.

I tried

```
<p align="center"><small>
<div style="text-align: left; display: inline-block; width: 300px;">
- Total number of months included in the dataset <br>
- Net total amount of profit/losses over the entire period <br> 
- Average of the changes in profit/losses over the entire period <br> 
- Greatest increase in profits (date and amount) over the entire period <br> 
- Greatest decrease in losses (date and amount) over the entire period <br> 
</div>
</small></p>
```

But it didnt work